# How to convert pandas type <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta'> to Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, time-series

```
TimeSeries = pandas.Series(df['time_col'].values.tolist())
pandas.to_timedelta(TimeSeries).mean()
```

After taking `mean()` I need to convert it to `TimeStamp` datatype to add it to `DataFrame`.

Below lines are not working

```
pandas.to_timestamp(pandas.to_timedelta(TimeSeries).mean())
pandas.Timestamp(pandas.to_timedelta(TimeSeries).mean())
```

Thanks in advance,
Ragu

Answer (score 0):

For convert timedelta to timestamp is necessary add some datetime, e.g:

```
import pandas as pd

out = pd.to_datetime('2000-01-01') + pd.to_timedelta(TimeSeries).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `total_seconds` of the mean timedelta and feed it to `pd.Timestamp` with the correct unit specified:

```
import pandas as pd
# example Series:
TimeSeriesDelta = pd.Series(pd.to_timedelta(['00:00:02.285932', 
                                             '00:00:11.366717', 
                                             '00:00:11.367594']))

timestamp = pd.Timestamp(TimeSeriesDelta.mean().total_seconds(), unit='s')
# Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:08.340081')
```

Note that this will add a date, 1970-01-01.